# Расположение картинок

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как более менее сделать расположение картинок друг за другом и лесенкой.Сделал так,но это очень не универсально,и не удобно на мой взгляд

```
#i2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 19px;
    z-index: -1;
    width:235px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#i3{
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: -2;
    width:220px;   
}
```

Вот весь пример http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/to0hcfy7/3/
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

1. внешний контейнер, дабы зафиксировать размер
2. nth-child, с целью не придумывать классы, либо генерация соотв стилей на javascript
3. центрирование абсолютно-спозиционированного элемента

плоский список картинок как в вопросе, гибко и кроссбраузерно, но при этом на чистом css, пожалуй - только подобным образом: (стоит использовать миксин препроцессора, чтобы свернуть повторяющийся код и поддержать такую глубину, как необходимо)

```css
gallery-preview {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 310px;
  height: 310px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
img:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%:
}
img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
  height 90%;
  width: 90%;
  top: 10%;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
  height 80%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
}
img:hover {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<gallery-preview>
  <img id="first" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtwaOFm5x207suB5vq5gM48ii7HjYWWg8TtOGRojCjsjs1VEC0" />
  <img id="i2" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-J6yPcDCmk5w/VOsya5JPDiI/AAAAAAAAChA/V3kcmDdbmpQ/s1600/jQuery%2BInterview%2BQuestions%2Band%2BAnswers.png" />
  <img id="i3" src="http://centrecon.ru/sites/default/files/field/image/123.jpeg" />
</gallery-preview>
```

Далее, существует свойство css3 `transform: translateZ()`, `transform: scale()` , а также прочие трансформации, посредством которых можно сделать код ещё проще - избежав необходимости что-либо центрировать и менять размер (перспективу) уже вообще одним числом.

И самое правильное решение - вложить картинки в контейнеры рекурсивно (можно скриптом):

```
<div class="cn">
  <img src="...">
  <div class="cn">
    <img src="...">
    <div class="cn">
      <img src="..."> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Тогда, селектора потребуется всего два: `.cs > img { ... }` и `.cs > .cs {...}`, и CSS-правила получаются относительные.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать это вот так при помощи JS:

1. располагаем все элементы друг под другом в одном контейнере;
2. находим все картинки, например, `document.querySelectorAll('b-container img')`;
3. к каждому элементу применяем свойство CSS `transform: translateY(Xpx) scale(X)`.

[jsFiddle с полным примером](http://jsfiddle.net/to0hcfy7/5/):

```
imgs.forEach(function(item) {
    item.style.transform = 'translateY(' + down + 'px) ' + 
        'scale(' + scale + ')';
    down += downStep;
    scale -= scaleStep;
});
```

Плюсы **+** :

1. свойство `transform` не вызывают перерасчет стилей, поэтому это будет происходить быстро при любом количестве картинок на странице;
2. не надо писать под каждую картинку свой стиль.

Минусы **-** :

1. поскольку картинки должны быть в изначальном положении одна над другой, мы привязываемся достаточно сильно к их размерам;
2. плюс свойства `transform` в данной ситуации рождает минус. Необходимо предусмотреть в размерах контейнера, что картинки будут сдвигаться вниз.